# Rails 5 Left Outer Join combined with a WHERE query

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following query on my `User` model:

```
def self.leaders
  self.left_joins(:user_tasks)
    .group(:id)
    .order("COUNT(user_tasks.id) DESC")
end
```

However I only want to query the `user_tasks` where `status: 'approved'`.

The following does not succesfully query the user_tasks table:

```
def self.leaders
  self.left_joins(:user_tasks)
    .where(status: 'approved')
    .group(:id)
    .order("COUNT(user_tasks.id) DESC")
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding the relevant table-name in the where clause?

```
.where("user_tasks.status" => 'approved')
```

If this does not work, please run `to_sql` on your query and edit your question and add the resulting sql there so we can have a look at it :)